# How to best create a "hand print" on a rigged model using said rigged model

Tags: displacement, pose-mode, dynamic-paint

I am trying to make a character touch part of their own body, and in turn make that part of the body conform to the shape of the hand (as skin does when you poke at it).

So far I have tried to use the Dynamic Paint Displace feature, which I believe would work, but the only problem is that I am unsure how to apply a canvas to one portion of the mesh, and the brush to another (if it's even possible!).

What I am currently trying (and what I assume is the incorrect way to achieve this) is to duplicate the hand mesh as a separate object (object2), and then use object2 as the brush, and the original body/model (object1) as the canvas. The issue arose when I realized that the original hand on object1 was being affected too.

I thought it would be as simple as deleting the hand mesh, and there would be no Issues. Problem is, when I delete the hand mesh, the ENTIRE rigged model changes shape. (photos attached)

TL;DR - I'm looking for a good way for a model to touch part of their own skin and have the skin deform around it (as in real life) without breaking the rig.

[image: Before]

[image: After]